# Continuous dependence on the right-hand side of a nonlinear PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

Let $x \in \Omega$ ($\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a bounded set with a sufficiently smooth boundary) and let us suppose that we have a PDE defined as

$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial t} &= A(u(t,x)) + F(u(t,x)),\\[10pt]
u(t,x)|_{\partial \Omega} &= 0,
\end{cases}$$

in which $A$ is a linear operator (which does not depend on either $t$ or $x$ so it is basically a matrix) and $F$ is a nonlinear operator with some nice properties (bounded, Lipschitz property, etc.) which describes the spatial dependence. We know that this equation has a unique solution.

What are the usual techniques to show that the solution of this problem depends continuously on the right-hand side, meaning that if we consider the modified problem

$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial u_{\varepsilon}(t,x)}{\partial t} & = A(u_{\varepsilon}(t,x)) + F(u_{\varepsilon}t,x)) + \varepsilon,\\[10pt]
u_{\varepsilon}(t,x)|_{\partial \Omega} &= 0,
\end{cases}$$
then $\Vert u - u_{\varepsilon} \Vert \rightarrow 0$ as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$?

I have tried to use the variation of parameters formula (the operator semigroup version) but to no avail. I would be grateful even for some references since usually "continuous dependence" means the one considering the initial value, and not the right-hand side one.

Comment: I think you can get this estimate just by variation of parameters formula . Now I don't quite understand why you denote $u_{\epsilon }$ in the second problem, does $u_{\epsilon }$ have any meaning? by example $u_{\epsilon } = u+\epsilon$? looks like the first problem with a nonlinearity $G = F(u(x,t))+\varepsilon$

Comment: @Ilovemath Here $u_{\varepsilon}$ is the solution of the second (modified) equation: I wanted to make a distinction between the two problems and their solutions (the second can be also written in the form of the first one, but that would not help us in the proof). If we could prove something like $u_{\varepsilon} = u + \varepsilon$, then the statement is proved.

My problem with the variation of parameters formula is that we get the term $F(u(s)) - F(u_{\varepsilon} (s))$ which should tend to zero as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$, but I cannot see how it can be proved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by remarking that $u_\epsilon -u$ verifies
$$
\frac{(\partial u_\epsilon(t,x)-u(t, x))}{\partial t}=A(u(t, x)-u_\epsilon(t,x))+F(u(t, x))+F(u_\epsilon(t, x))-F(u(t, x)))+\epsilon
$$
Now multiplying the previous equation by $u_\epsilon -u$ and integrating over $\Omega$ we obtain
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{d}{dt} \int_\Omega  \vert u_\epsilon(t,x)-u(t, x) \vert^2&=\int_\Omega A (u_\epsilon(t,x)-u(t, x))^2\\
&+\int_\Omega F(u_\epsilon(t, x))-F(u(t, x))) (u_\epsilon(t, x)-u(t,x))\\
&+ \int_\Omega \epsilon (u_\epsilon(t,x)-u(t, x))
\end{align}
Now, you use the assumptions you have on $A$ (Matrix) and $F$ (L-Lipschitz), the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality as well as the inequality $ab \leq \dfrac{1}{2} (a^2+b^2) \; \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ to eventually obtain
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{d}{dt} \int_\Omega  \vert u_\epsilon(t,x)-u(t, x) \vert^2&\leq  \Vert A \Vert \Vert u_\epsilon-u\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2\\
&+L \Vert u_\epsilon-u \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2\\
&+ \dfrac{\epsilon^2}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2} \Vert u_\epsilon -u \Vert^2_{L^2(\Omega)}
\end{align}
Now use Gronwall inequality  to obtain
$$
\Vert u_\epsilon-u \Vert^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq exp\big(2t \big( \Vert A \Vert + L +1 \big)\Bigg( \bigg(\Vert u_\epsilon(0,.)-u(0,.) \Vert^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \Big)+ \epsilon^2 t \Bigg)
$$
I'm assuming that for the initial conditions you have $u_\epsilon(0,x)=u(0,x)+\epsilon$ as well, so by substitution you get
$$
\Vert u_\epsilon-u \Vert^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq exp\big(2t \big( \Vert A \Vert + L +1 \big)\Bigg( \bigg(\epsilon^2 meas(\Omega) \Big)+ \epsilon^2 t \Bigg)
$$
Finally you can deduce that $\underset{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}{\lim} \Vert u_\epsilon-u \Vert^2_{L^2(\Omega)}=0.$

Comment: How can we use the Lipschitz property for the term $\int_{\Omega} (F(u_{\varepsilon}) - F(u))(u_{\varepsilon} - u)$? Shouldn't we need $\int_{\Omega} (F(u_{\varepsilon}) - F(u))^2$ there to be able to use it?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you can use the inequality $ab \leq \dfrac{1}{2}(a^2 + b^2)$ there, but then the constants are a bit different.